# Connecting a Flux to a Mono

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a `Flux<T>` that returns multiple `T`s. I need to wait until all the items are emitted from my Flux before continuing on to the Mono. When I was doing similarly with just Monos, I was able to zip them together (using `zipWhen()`) to achieve this effect. For now I'm setting up and doing the second set of actions in the Flux's `doOnComplete()`, but it doesn't seem like the best solution.

Note that I'm fairly new to Flux and Mono

```
    getFlux()
        .doOnComplete(
            () -> {
              // 1a. Retrieve ids from results of the flux
              @NotNull List<String> ids = extractIds(dto.objects); // objects is populated by the Flux
              Mono<?> myOtherMono =
                    getMono1(ids)
                      .zipWhen(
                          // create second mono
                          });
              
              Flux<List<?>> otherFlux =
                  getOtherFlux(ids);
              myOtherMono .and(otherFlux).block();
            })
        .blockLast();
```

Edited to add more detail:
One of the answers suggested using the `then` method to essentially turn it into a Mono. I did so, but now it seems to be ignoring the code in the `zipWhen`. See below:

```
    getFlux()
        .then()
        .zipWhen( // should continue here when the other mono completes, but it's never getting in here
            (x) -> {
              // 1a. Retrieve ids from results of the flux
              @NotNull List<String> ids = extractIds(dto.objects); // objects is populated by the Flux
              Mono<?> myOtherMono =
                    getMono1(ids)
                      .zipWhen(
                          // create second mono
                          });
              
              Flux<List<?>> otherFlux =
                  getOtherFlux(ids);
              Mono<?> otherFluxAsMono = otherFlux.then()
              return myOtherMono.zipWith(otherFluxAsMono);
            })
        .block();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a list of all the elements that your flux had, you can use collect
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-

example:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And after that you can use a map or flatmap or any Mono operator.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need `then(Mono<V> other)` operator of the `Flux`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-

```
/**
 * Let this {@link Flux} complete then play signals from a provided {@link Mono}.
 * <p>
 * In other words ignore element from this {@link Flux} and transform its completion signal into the
 * emission and completion signal of a provided {@code Mono<V>}. Error signal is
 * replayed in the resulting {@code Mono<V>}.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/thenWithMonoForFlux.svg" alt="">
 *
 * <p><strong>Discard Support:</strong> This operator discards elements from the source.
 *
 * @param other a {@link Mono} to emit from after termination
 * @param <V> the element type of the supplied Mono
 *
 * @return a new {@link Flux} that wait for source completion then emits from the supplied {@link Mono}
 */
public final <V> Mono<V> then(Mono<V> other) {
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works. When I use the then method, it ends up skipping the rest of the code. I'll update the question with more details

Comment: I didn't suggest to use a `then()` exactly which is essentially a `Mono<Void>` without any possible action afterward since there is just no data in the `Mono<Void>`. I suggested to use a `then(Mono<V> other)` where you can create a new `Mono` to return based on some data you have so far.

Comment: Oh, I couldn't figure out how to use that. I got it working with the other answer, though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure! But you didn't say in your question that you really need the whole data from that `Flux`. Sorry, if I misunderstood you from the beginning.